# How to remove white refraction spots

Tags: post-processing

I'm having some difficulty removing shiny white spots caused by refraction and reflection of sunlight through my wide-angle lens.
Is there a better way of removing these spots rather than going through *spot remover* in Lightroom and removing each one by hand?

Or just **don't take pictures of the sun directly?**

[Here's the original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8ACt.png) and [here's a close up of a part of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3gLz.png) for closer inspection, so you can see exactly what I mean.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What aperture were you using?

Comment: @MichaelClark f/14

Answer (score 9):

Have you already checked your lens and sensor for dust? If not, **don't clean them yet**. *If* the problem is caused by dust, you *may* be able to **use a photograph of the specks as a mask** to guide their removal in your existing images. Also **do not use any automated dust removal feature built into your camera** until *after* you get a clean shot of the dust that you are able to successfully use to post process your existing images.

If the specks are fairly consistent across images, but you've already cleaned your lens and sensor, you can reuse a mask that you manually create for one image.

If the specks are moving around, they may still be caused by dust on your sensor. If your camera has in-body image stabilization, the sensels won't map directly to image pixels. This would make post processing the images more troublesome because you'd likely have to manually align the mask. (See [How can I automatically digitally remove shifting sensor dust speckles from a large series of photos?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/99315/75526))

---

Unfortunately, most automated ways of removing specks like these will degrade image quality. If the specks are limited to the sky, it is fairly straightforward to limit noise-reduction to desired areas with a layer mask.

The most time efficient way of dealing with these images would be to use them at reduced size, where the defect simply isn't visible. (Basically, ignoring the problem.) You can spend more time removing specks from only the images you really want to enlarge.

Answer (score 5):

> Or just don't take pictures of the sun directly?

Assuming the artifacts are caused by dust on the sensor (they probably wouldn't be so well defined if the dust were in your lens), you can lessen their influence by using a larger aperture. Of course, this will probably require a neutral density filter to compensate for the change in exposure since you're already probably close to your camera's minimum shutter time.

The particles may even be directly on the sensor surface, rather than on the front of the filter stack directly in front of the sensor. For more about that, please see [How can I tell if a scratch is directly on my sensor or on the filter above it?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/99569/15871) and [What are these purple pixels on my Canon 60D and how do I get rid of them?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/82295/15871)

If your camera has an automatic dust delete feature, performing a sample frame might be useful if the artifacts are in the same place on every image. If they're moving around every image, then dust on your sensor probably isn't the culprit.

Comment: _you can lessen their influence by using a larger aperture._ The drawback of this advice (in general) when shooting directly at the sun is that you don't get diffraction spikes that are typical of small-aperture shooting. (But in the case of this particular photo, the diffraction spikes weren't prominent anyways, so the advice applies without said drawback)

Comment: @scottbb I've often found with trees that large and such an irregular surface that diffraction spikes aren't normally very prominent, if present at all. Although most of my experience with that has been with stars at night.

Comment: yeah, I've also struggled to capture bright-sun diffraction spikes with irregular field stops such as trees, without underexposing the scene.

Comment: Hey, and not everyone necessarily *wants* diffraction spikes.